# Correlated Equilibrium

Tags: optimization, game-theory

I have a question about the definition of the correlated equilibrium.

I see that some authors define it as "expected payoff of playing the recommended strategy is no less than playing another strategy". Here the inequalities are for each recommended strategy of each player. (http://www.stanford.edu/~saberi/lecture6.pdf)
[image]

Others define it as "expected payoff is no less than playing other strategies". Here the inequalities are one per player. (http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-123-microeconomic-theory-iii-spring-2010/lecture-notes/MIT14_123S10_lec08.pdf)

[image]

So which one is correct?

Are they both equivalent ?

I think that the first implies the second by the second does not imply the first.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please state the inequalities in the question and explain the notation? Questions here should be self-contained.

Comment: Using two different notations for the same objects in one single questions is really not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume **finite games** for simplicity. Without any loss of generality we can take the space of randomization of the correlated device as the outcome space $\Omega=S$ and the recommended strategy as simply the identity, $s(\omega)=\omega \in S$. Remember the outcome space, $S$, is the product of the actions (or strategies) of each player, $S=\Pi S_i$. Let $P$ be a probability distribution over $S$ then $P$ is a correlated eq. iff: 
$$ P(a_i=x)>0\Rightarrow\sum_{a_{-i}\in S_{-i}} u_i(x,a_{-i})P(a_{-i}|a_i=x) \ge \sum_{a_{-i}\in S_{-i}} u_i(y,a_{-i})P(a_{-i}|a_i=x)\quad\forall x,y\in S_i,\,\forall i$$

or equivalently, $$ \sum_{a\in S} u_i(a)P(a) \ge \sum_{a\in S} u_i(d(a_i),a_{-i})P(a)\quad\forall d:S_i\rightarrow S_i,\,\forall i.$$

These two definitions are equivalent.